# mysql query for find all the rows,whose edited_date is not changed between 48 to 72 hrs only

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a orders table.There is a column in that table named edited_date.
I want all the rows to be printed whose edited_date>48 to 72 hrs only.Only in between that period.
I am using mysql.How do i do it??

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Select 
*
from orders 
where DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), edited_date) between 2 and 3
```